# Getting a libstc++-6.dll related error when I run a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, mingw

I'm trying to compile a Qt app I wrote "from scratch". I installed Qt5 and MSYS/MinGW (I'm on Windows 7). I know the app works because I previously compiled it on a different computer. From a folder containing nothing but the `.cpp`s and `.h`s, I run:

```
qmake
```

Then I go into the generated project file and add the line `QT += widgets`, and then run

```
make
```

This compiles without errors and I really thought I had it, but then when I run the executable I get:

> The procedure entry point _ZNSt18condition_variable4waitERSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE could not be located in the dynamic link library libstc++-6.dll.

This seems to be something about needing to include the C++ standard library in my includepath, but I have no idea which directory on my computer that would be or how to include it.

Comment: ***This seems to be something about needing to include the C++ standard library in my includepath*** No this is nothing about includes. It means you have an incompatible `libstc++-6.dll` in your system `PATH` (where windows searches for dlls and executables) compared to the one that built the Qt dlls.

Comment: @drescherjm It seems it's using the one in `C:\mingw\bin`. How can I figure out which one I should be using?

Comment: It should be the one you link against. This seems that your linker is using different dll than the one that is used at runtime.